# Flatten or "explode" an array-valued field, in an array of objects?

Tags: json, stream, jq

I have this data:

```json
[
  { "path": "x", "types": ["a", "b"] },
  { "path": "y", "types": ["c", "d"] }
]
```

And I am looking to obtain this output:

```json
{ "path": "x", "type": "a" }
{ "path": "x", "type": "b" }
{ "path": "y", "type": "c" }
{ "path": "y", "type": "d" }
```

How would I do this with Jq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
.[] | {path, type: .types[]}
```

```json
{"path":"x","type":"a"}
{"path":"x","type":"b"}
{"path":"y","type":"c"}
{"path":"y","type":"d"}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/IIflXPYHk9)

Use the `--compact-output` or `-c` option to also have the same *compact* formatting.

---

Edit:

> This is documented in [the manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) under the heading "Object Construction: `{}`". Specifically the statement, "If one of the expressions produces multiple results, multiple dictionaries will be produced."

Thanks to [@shadowtalker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70176007/flatten-or-explode-an-array-valued-field-in-an-array-of-objects/70176039?noredirect=1#comment124070536_70176039) for looking it up.

Comment: Note that this is documented in [the manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) under the heading "Object Construction: `{}`". Specifically the statement, "If one of the expressions produces multiple results, multiple dictionaries will be produced." You might want to add this to your answer!